# Unity 2D animation seems blocked

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have an animation in Unity, its 2D, made from Sprites.

My animation is blocked, I mean, I can't add a new sprite, click play button, or add a new Property.

Comment: You really need to show some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to animate an object in Unity you have to have a valid object selected, that is to say, the object can be animated. 
This is typically a game object that is selected in the hierarchy.

Without this, how does the animation window know what it can and can't animate? That is the way that properties are animated in Unity, it needs to know what it is supposed to be animating, the valid object tells it what can be animated. Without this knowledge, the animation window will lock down certain features, adding keys and playing the animation.

In your case, select the game object that you want to have animated and, if you have a valid animator controller in place, the animation window will set itself up with all the necessary bits and pieces, namely the animation clips. Then you can animate to your hearts content.

Here's the animation window reference:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html

Hopefully this answers your question.